# Why am I getting "Argument of \<counter> has an extra }" error

Tags: latex

Learning loops in latex in this [sample document](https://www.overleaf.com/project/5fe9cf436b86683ce43637c9) on overleaf.com

I am using `\newcount\index` to create a named count for controlling loop iterations.

*myMacro* executes 3 times as expected but the log shows some errors.

Are errors because `\index` is reserved  ?

Not sure what to change to make document errorless.

Entire simple sample document

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\def\myMacro(#1) 
{
\section{p=#1}
}

% http://www.texfaq.org/FAQ-repeat-num
\newcount\index
\loop
  \myMacro(\the\index)
  \advance \index +1
\ifnum \index<3
\repeat

\end{document}
```

produces output desired

[image]

but there are 3 errors in log tagged at the `\repeat`

```
main.tex, line 17
Argument of \index has an extra }.

<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.17 \repeat
            
I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
For example, `\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce
this error. If you simply proceed now, the `\par' that
I've just inserted will cause me to report a runaway
argument that might be the root of the problem. But if
your `}' was spurious, just type `2' and it will go away.

 main.tex, line 17
Runaway argument?

! Paragraph ended before \index was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.17 \repeat
            
I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.

 main.tex, line 17
You can't use `\par' after \the.

<recently read> \par 
                     
l.17 \repeat
            
I'm forgetting what you said and using zero instead.
```

Comment: Can you make a [mre] and not just a code fragment?

Comment: (I don't know what you want to do with loops, but personally I find `pgffor` loops the easiest way to do loops in latex)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the argument of the section title is not only used for the title, but also written to the .toc file for use in the table of contents. You could either choose another short title for the toc that does not depend on your counter or you can workaround the problem by storing the index in a counter:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\newcounter{foo}

%\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\newcommand{\myMacro}[1]{
\setcounter{foo}{#1}
\section{p=\thefoo}
}

% http://www.texfaq.org/FAQ-repeat-num
\newcount\index
\loop
  \myMacro{\the\index}
  \advance \index +1
\ifnum \index<3
\repeat

\end{document}
```